# Join two sets of data where key is not required in both

Tags: oracle, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am attempting to create a report in SSRS with an Oracle data source. The solution to this issue can be in SSRS but it would be preferable to be in Oracle. I do not have access to modify the tables or to create anything in the database.

Given the following table layout (Note that these tables are simplifications via sub queries of the tables that are actually being queried.):

**Table 1 (Bills)**

```
AccountID  Period      Tax
--------------------------
123        13/10     21.12
123        13/11      6.46
123        13/12      5.28
```

**Table 2 (Adjustments)**

```
AccountID  Period      Tax
--------------------------
123        13/11    -16.66
123        14/01      5.00
```

I am looking for results similar to this:

```
AccountID  Period      Tax
--------------------------
123        13/10     21.12
123        13/11    -10.20
123        13/12      5.28
123        14/01      5.00
```

As you can see, there can be records in the Adjustments table for a period and not have a corresponding record in the Bills table for the same period (and vice versa). I am having difficulty wrapping my head around how to modify my query to make this work. The below query is a pseudocode version of the current query I am using.

```
SELECT A.AccountID, NVL(B.Period, C.Period) "Period", NVL(A.Tax, 0) + NVL(B.Tax, 0) "Tax"
FROM Account A
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT AccountID, Period, SUM(Tax) "Tax"
                 FROM Bills 
             GROUP BY AccountID, Period) B ON A.AccountID = B.AccountID 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT AccountID, Period, SUM(Tax) "Tax"
                 FROM Adjustments
             GROUP BY AccountID, Period) C ON A.AccountID = C.AccountID
WHERE NVL(A.Tax, 0) + NVL(B.Tax, 0) <> 0
```

Hopefully this is enough information. Please let me know if any more information is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c7b27/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Bills ( AccountID , Period,      Tax )
AS
          SELECT 123, '13/10', 21.12 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 123, '13/11', 6.46 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 123, '13/12', 5.28 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Adjustments ( AccountID , Period,      Tax )
AS
          SELECT 123, '13/11', -16.66 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 123, '14/01', 5.00 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT AccountID, Period, SUM( Tax ) AS Tax
FROM   ( SELECT * FROM Bills
         UNION ALL
         SELECT * FROM Adjustments )
GROUP BY AccountID, Period
ORDER BY AccountID, Period
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c7b27/3/0)**:

```
| ACCOUNTID | PERIOD |   TAX |
|-----------|--------|-------|
|       123 |  13/10 | 21.12 |
|       123 |  13/11 | -10.2 |
|       123 |  13/12 |  5.28 |
|       123 |  14/01 |     5 |
```

Comment: So obvious but I couldn't see it. Thanks so much.